# What is causing the Colon Expected Error in Python?

Tags: python

I am trying to get my head around Expected Colon Error in the following code. Any help appreciated.

The code is -

```
    if df.loc['pivot'] > df.loc['Open'] :
        df.loc['Signal'] = 1

    elif df.loc[['Open'] > df.loc['IB'] and df.loc['Open'] > df.loc['pivot'] and df.loc['Open'] < df.loc['OB']:
        df.loc['Signal'] = 0

    elif (((df.loc['Open']) <= (((df.loc['2_pips']) - 5)/ 1000)) * (df.loc['pivot'])) and ((df.loc['Open']) >= (((df.loc['1_pips']) + 10)/ 1000 * (df.loc['pivot']))) and ((df.loc['Open']) >= (df.loc['pivot'])) :
        df.loc['Signal'] = 1

    elif (df.loc['Open'] <= ((df.loc['1_pips'] * df.loc['pivot']) + df.loc['pivot'] )) and (df.loc['Open'] > (((df.loc['1_pips'] - 10) * df.loc['pivot']) + df.loc['pivot'])) :
        df.loc['Signal'] = 1

    elif ((df.loc['Open']  < OB) and (df.loc['Open']  < df.loc['pivot'])):
        df.loc['Signal'] = -1

    elif ((df.loc['Open']  <= OB) and (df.loc['Open']  >= IB) and (df.loc['Open']  < df.loc['pivot'])):
        df.loc['bs'] = 0

    elif (df.loc['Open'] < ((df.Loc['2_pips'] - 5) * df.loc['pivot']) + df.loc['pivot']) and (df.loc['Open'] > ((df.loc['1_pips'] + 10) * pivot) + df.loc['pivot']) and (df.loc['Open'] < df.loc['pivot']):
        df.loc['Signal'] = -1

    elif (df.loc['Open']  <= (df.loc['1_pips'] * df.loc['pivot']) + df.loc['pivot']) and (df.loc['Open']  > ((df.loc['1_pips'] - 10) * df.loc['pivot']) + df.loc['pivot']):
        df.loc['Signal'] = -1

    else:
        df.loc['Signal'] = 0
```

Thanks!

Comment: how this is related with javascript?

Answer (score 1):

On line 4, you have `df.loc[['Open']` which I guess is one square bracket too much.

You can also simplify that line as:

```
elif df.loc['Open'] > df.loc['IB'] and df.loc['pivot'] < df.loc['Open'] < df.loc['OB']:
```

And generally, you have way too many parentheses. I'm guessing that it's actually because you were trying to find the issue.

In general, when you get a compiler syntax error like an (un)expected token, you have a structural issue just *above* it. It is parsing the line it's complaining about as the continuation of the previous statement. Unmatched (), [] or {}. To find it, one could have reduced the code with the error and noticed that it was still failing with the same error, meaning that the actual error was in fact from the previous line(s).